# Error "is required to build" while installing from tar.gz

Tags: software-installation, tar, mega

To install I did the following in terminal.

1. `tar -zxvf nombre del paquete.tar.gz`
2. `cd` into file
3. `./configure`
4. `make`
5. `make install`

Tried the option 3 and got the following:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for GLIB... yes
checking for OPENSSL... yes
checking for LIBCURL... yes
checking for a2x... no
configure: error: a2x is required to build docs, install asciidoc
```

Comment: What is not clear? Install asciidoc.

Comment: Also before building from source - check the package on https://packages.ubuntu.com - it may be packaged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tar` is nothing more than a compressed file. There is not a certain way to "install" a `tar`. If what's inside is install-able software, it's up to the notes that accompany that software, to define how you are going to install it. Usually that notes are in plain `txt` file under the name of `README`. If there is a `make` file, then you will have to issue the above commands that you just mentioned. Else you will have to follow these instructions.

Though, since you are not downloading the software from a repository, you might face a series of dependencies that your machine will need. In some cases if all dependencies are identified by your package manager, all you have to do is a `sudo apt-get -f install`. You seem to run `./configure`, which it seems like a script that runs some commands to check those dependencies. Else you will have to debug step by step the installation process, by installing the packages yourself by `sudo apt-get install <package>`.